keyboardDismissBehavior on drag dismiss the keyboard always
after updating Flutter on 14-Dec-2024 to version 3.27.0, this happens
keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,

this line inside SingleChildScrollView always dismiss the keyboard without scrolling the UI
I noticed this line is removed in single_child_scroll_view.dart file at line #279
notification.dragDetails != null &&

see this video. https://www.veed.io/view/968e92cd-23e1-4c68-9895-a3aed846c8e8?panel=share&sharingWidget=true
any idea what to do now?

can you provide more info and use case you want to achieve?

The use case is simple: The keyboard should be dismissed only when dragging the scroll view. Currently, when I tap on the text field, the keyboard is dismissed.

below code can work same as scrollview's onDrag behaviours
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
    onVerticalDragDown: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
    child: SingleChildScrollView());


A quick fix that I found is to replace SingleChildScrollView with a ListView. Hope it helps!
